# Qt Application For Nokia N9 -- drawing anti-aliasing doesn't work

Tags: nokia, antialiasing, qwidget, qpainter

I am developing an app for Nokia N9. Cause I need to draw things, I use class inherited from QWidget and on paintEvent I use QPainter to draw a line.

It works, but line is aliased on my device, and antialiased on simulator.

I seems, that setRenderHints does not work at all and have no effect.

```
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
```

The text is aliased (drawText), but line is not. If I do:

```
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::TextAntialiasing, false);
```

Text is still aliased on N9 and not aliased in simulator. I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

there is hdge community of N9 and MeeGo developers willing to answer them, when only you will ask them question. You are to look for in: their forums and quickest way in meego devs chat. As Nokia N9 is common and MeeGo community share knowleadge and help I think you will find there help. Some places I thik you should visit:
IRC Channel

We use IRC for a variety of real-time conversations: meetings, discussion, troubleshooting, collaboration, chatting with other contributors, and more. Before joining, you should read our guidelines for participation and our community communication document.
Primary Channels

## meego at irc.freenode.net: 24/7 open discussion.

## meego-meeting at irc.freenode.net: scheduled IRC meetings.

Additional channels: focused on specific project topics.
Additional Information

If you are new to IRC, http://webchat.freenode.net/ and the IRC Prelude are good starting points.

At some point, you might miss an IRC client. There is probably one already installed in your system. Otherwise, there are plenty of free alternatives to choose from.

https://meego.com/community/irc-channel